# How could Grep account for multiple occurences in a row?

Tags: r

say I have:

```
test <- c("you", "he", "I", "you are", "you you")

grep("you", test, value = FALSE)
```

that gives me [1] 1 4 5

what can I do to account for double occurrence of 'you' in 5, maybe getting the result: [1] 1 4 5 5 instead?

Comment: isn't a vector like `1 0 0 1 2` more useful? `rep(seq_along(test), stringr::str_count(test, 'you'))`

Comment: @rawr it was just a suggestion, simply 4 would be the most useful output in my case I guess but I'm not fully sure yet. really the exact output format is kinda irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for (3) all are only two lines of code and except for (1) all use only base R.  All accept general regular expressions except for (2) and (5) which assume the more restrictive assumption of fixed strings -- the question's example uses a fixed string.

(1) seems the simplest while supporting regular expressions but (4) is only slightly more complicated while still supporting regular expressions and only using base R.

**1) strapplyc**  `strapplyc` extracts a list of all the `you` occurrences, one vector per component of `test`, and then `lengths` gives the length of each of those vectors giving `freq`.  Finally use `rep` to convert that to the desired form.  This solution or (4) seem the simplest of the ones we present.

```
library(gsubfn)

freq <- lengths(strapplyc(test, "you"))  # 1 0 0 1 2
rep(seq_along(freq), freq)
[1] 1 4 5 5
```

**2) gregexpr 1**  This is similar to the last one except it uses `gregexpr` instead of `strapplyc`.  The problem with `gregexpr` is its irregular output where it reports no occurrences as -1 so we append a "you" to each element of the input and then take lengths minus 1 so we don['t count the added `you`.   This one is only slightly more complex with an additional consideration regarding the odd way `gregexpr` indicates no matches; however, it does have the advantage that it only uses base R but it requires that the search term be fixed and not a regular expression.

```
freq <- lengths(gregexpr("you", paste(test, "you"))) - 1
rep(seq_along(freq), freq)
```

**3) gregexpr 2** This also uses `gregexpr` but uses a different approach to converting it to the desired form. Convert `g`, the output of `gregexpr`, to a data.frame using `stack`.  `stack` requires that the input list be named and we must also remove occurrences of -1 from `g` to get the right answer..  The result formed by `stack` is a two column data frame with factor column `ind` holding the solution.  Finally, convert `ind` to integer.

```
g <- gregexpr("you", test)
names(g) <- seq_along(g)
as.integer(as.character(stack(lapply(g, setdiff, -1L))$ind))

## [1] 1 4 5 5
```

**4) gregexpr 3**  This removes the -1's in the `gregexpr` output so that `lengths` can be used.  It only uses base R and also works with regular expressions.

```
g <- gregexpr("you", test)
rep(seq_along(g), lengths(lapply(g, setdiff, -1L)))
## [1] 1 4 5 5
```

**5) count.fields** Another base R solution is to use `count.fields` which will count the fields between the occurrences of `you` so we subtract one to get the occurrences of `you` itself.  This one can only handle fixed strings whereas the other solutions can handle regular expressions.

```
freq <- count.fields(textConnection(test), sep = "you") - 1
rep(seq_along(freq), freq)
## [1] 1 4 5 5
```

Comment: cool, thank you, that would do the trick
however, i wouldn't want to just copy that as it is definitely out of my league. if i just do

gregexpr("you", test)

i get an output that i can't deal with, why is that? or can you briefly explain your code?

Comment: thank you so much! is it ok for me to just use the gregexpr 2 approach on an university assignment? i will mention that i have that from the internet, although it's really very obvious.

Comment: It's fine with me if it's ok with your instructor.

Comment: Have added **4) gregexpr 3**